# How to set LI to behave like table cell

Tags: html, css

i want to make a menu using lists (`ul` and `li`).
As regards that using table-cell property is not cross browser, how to styling `li`s to have fixed with like table cells fit to it's container?

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|      Item 1      |      Item 2      |      Item 3      |      Item 7      |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Notes:
 1. I'm forced to use list and could not use table
 2. We don't know how many items exists
 3. I want to do that without JavaScript
 4. We don't know how width is the container
 5. parent `ul` should be just `100%` in width, don't use static width please

Comment: Why are you forced not to use table?

Comment: That's the manager order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Semantically, a menu is a list, so using `<li>` is more appropriate than a `<table>`.  WC3 has a decent outline of how to do it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_float5). To fix the width, set both the widths of the `<ul>` and the `<li>`s.

Answer (score 4):

```
ul li {float: left; width: 100px;}
```

Something like this?

Or like this: http://jsfiddle.net/qLxSh/

Comment: This is definitely how you do it. The one question is if you are floating the divs and you do not know how many you have, you may need to start a second row. If you are doing this dynamically with PHP you can clear a row after a certain number of "cells" are filled. If not, you may be able to us CSS child selector to clear each row after they are filled.

Comment: i don't want to start second row

Comment: You don't need to do so. My example just showing what happen if you'll have to much of elements - they will drop to the next line if there will be not enough space.

Comment: but It does not fit to it's container, parent `ul` should be `100%` in width

Comment: When displaying this items - can you count them first?

Comment: I'm just designing template in presentation layer. so i don't have any information about count and width

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6825/discussion-between-omid-amraei-and-giker)

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there are too many don'ts to make this as flexible as it should be.

Answer (score 1):

```
ul li { float: left; }
```

or

```
ul li { display: inline-block; }
```

Note that "display: inline-block;" does not work well on IE6 and IE7. On these browsers, you have to replace

```
ul li { display: inline-block; }
```

with

```
ul li { display: inline; zoom: 1; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the best way, using css display options: [jsFiddle demo](http://goo.gl/c3tkVg)